Надо угадать три числа, но угадав третье число, две другие тоже разгадываются. Как исправить
Смотрите у меня по рандому три цифры они могут быть похожими и если отгадать число 1 оно заменяется и проблема в том что отгадав третье, две первые становятся очевидными
Вот HTML:


var time = 59.99;

var stop = setInterval(function Boom() {
  time -= 0.01;
  time = Math.floor(time * 100) / 100;
  document.getElementById("time").textContent =
    `Time: ${time}`;

  if (time === 0) {
    clearInterval(stop);
  }
}, 10);


let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

let num3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

console.log(num1, num2, num3);

document.getElementById("password").textContent = `Password: ${0}--${0}--${0}`

function getUserInp() {
  let userInp =
    Number(document.getElementById("input").value);
  console.log(userInp);

  if (num1 === userInp) {
    alert("правильно");

    document.getElementById("password").textContent =
      `Password: ${num1}--${0}--${0}`
    userInp = '';
    num1 = String(num1);
  }
  if (num2 === userInp) {
    alert("2 правильно");

    document.getElementById("password").textContent = `Password: ${num1}--${num2}--${0}`
    userInp = '';
    num2 = String(num2);
  }
  if (num3 === userInp) {
    alert("3 правильно");

    document.getElementById("password").textContent =
      `Password: ${num1}--${num2}--${num3}`
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bomb Game</h1>
  <div class="timer">

    <p id="time">Timer: <br> 00:00
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="pass">
    <p id="password">Пароль:<br> 0--0--0
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="userinp">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введи цифру" id="input">
    <br>
    <button onclick="getUserInp()">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>



userInp = " "; И num = String(num); Я сделал для того что бы если num1 & num2 одинаковы оно не говорило ответ второго и пользователь сам угадал повторно введя цифру но если он угадает num3 вы видете что он сразу выведет все три. Что я хочу: что бы при угадывании 3 выводился только он. И по возможности если это можно сделать код короче.

Ну так у вас и при угадывании второго первое отображается

чтобы вывести только третье число, не выводя первые два, в коде должна быть примерно такая строчка: Password: ${0}--${0}--${num3}. А такой строчки в коде нет. Поэтому как-то странно ожидать описанного поведения.

У меня другая идея как сделать что бы не угадав 1 ты не можешь угадать 2 и 3 я на завтра попытаюсь сделать но хотелось бы посмотреть как правильно
